# How to select individual cells from a Range in a specified order, using an index number?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I could just use a collection of ranges, but I thought I could take advantage of the existing functionality of the Range object to select individual items in a specified order.  That way I have fewer objects to manage.

For example, I have specified my range as:
`Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("C11,C9,C7,D6,F6,H6,I7,I9,I11")`.
Note that these cells will not necessarily be in an obvious order or pattern.

When I do something like a `For each` loop, I can easily cycle through those cells in that specific order.  I want to be able to similarly be able to select individual items from the list (in that order) at will, for example select the 4th cell from my list.

I have found that the `Range.Areas` object gets me pretty close to what I am after, but if I go back later and add to my range, doing something like `Union(myrange, activesheet.Range("C10"))` my first 3 cells are now merged into a single area.  It does not show this same functionality if I were to declare C10 in my initial list.

So my question is either:  Is there another way to select individual cells by index;  OR is there a "Union"-like function that will keep cells discrete without merging ranges.

Comment: The idiomatic and performant way to iterate cells is with a `For Each` loop, given `Range` is a collection of objects. Not clear why the order matters at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the Areas of your discontiguous loop then loop through each cell in each area.

```
dim a as long, c as long, myRange as range
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("C11,C9,C7,D6,F6,H6,I7,I9,I11")
for a=1 to myrange.areas.count
    for c=1 to myrange.areas(a).cells.count
        'do something with myrange.areas(a).cells(c)
        debug.print myrange.areas(a).cells(c).address(0,0)
    next c
next a
```

Comment: So what if I want to access just the 6th cell?  Do I have to do a loop to count up to the 6th cell each time?  I want to be able to do something like myrange.something(6), is that possible?

Comment: I suppose you could make a string array of the addresses and then access individual elements of the string but a union of cells **wants** to group cells together into areas if it can.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to index individual items, then create an **array of ranges** to assist you:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim myrange As Range, ary() As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("C11,C9,C7,D6,F6,H6,I7,I9,I11")
    i = 1
    ReDim ary(1 To myrange.Count)

    For Each a In myrange
        Set ary(i) = a
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

Then you could use `ary(6)` to get the **sixth** item, etc.
If the number of items is fixed, then you can avoid the `ReDim`.